# Using social network to login to Windows Phone 7/8 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like for users to login to my app using existing credentials from FB, Twitter, Google, Yahoo ect.  The idea behind this is I would then capture their userId and possible name information and save/use it.

I'm not familiar with any control that currently allows this for the Windows Phone 7/8 - Does anyone know of a control kind of like what JanRain or oneall.com offers for web sites but for the Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method published by Bruno Terkaly: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2011/11/20/video-tutorial-how-to-add-identity-to-mobile-applications-windows-phone-7-and-the-access-control-service-facebook-yahoo-google-live-id.aspx